# Declaring function as return type in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3.7 I may declare types for functions and methods. I know that it is optional and I may not do it. But Python is not my main language and this feature helps me a lot and makes my code more readable.

But I cannot find a correct type for closures. Could you help me?

```py
def external_function(closure_param: str) -> ???:
    def inner_function(param: str) -> bool:
        # some code
    return inner_function
```

I was searching for a correct type in built-in packages `typing` and `types` but didn't find suitable.

Comment: Would anyone like to check out my new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56518390/11279883

Answer (score 1):

Python has a module called `types` and its main purpose is to store built-in types that aren't available in builtins.py. FunctionType, the type you are looking to return is in types.py. Now to rewrite your code.

```
from types import FunctionType
def externalfunction(closure_param: str) -> FunctionType:
    def internalfunction(param: str) -> bool:
        # some code
        pass
    return internalfunction
```

Comment: Nope, this is not the correct way to annotate this. Especially since it isn't a method at all, it's a normal function

Comment: I edited it to be FunctionType

Comment: Yes, but you should still use `typing.Callable` and fully annotate it with argument types and return types. Inany case, this question is a duplicate

Comment: I have finally found the answer. This is a `Callable` type from `typing`. This is a quote from the doc `Callable type; Callable[[int], str] is a function of (int) -> str.`.

Comment: @Mark I noticed you had edited my post, would you like to check out my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56518390/11279883